# Why do the audio elements look different and have different features on Mac vs iPad?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, ipad, volume, airplay

I made a website with a table of tunes, where each row has a column for a media player. Here's a link to the site: https://barb-elliott.github.io/TuneList/.

When I look at the website (in Chrome) on Mac it's fine, but on iPad it's different: it has the text "Error" and an airplay icon. I care most about how it works on the iPad and would like to get rid of the airplay icon and "Error" text in that context and make sure the play/pause and playback speed work, volume if possible.

On Mac it shows a play button, time beginning and end (0:00/4:25 e.g.) a volume icon, and vertical ellipse, which brings up the playback speed options.

On iPad (v. 17.1.1) it shows the play button, the text "Error", an airplay icon, and an ellipse icon, which brings up the playback speed options.

See the attached image if that helps.

[how the audio controls look on Mac, iPad, and iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg7jB.png)

NOTE: It's intentional that when you hit pause the counter goes back to 0:00.

So far I tried using my Mac to debug (I'm very inexpert at using the debugger) but it looked fine in that view. What I did specifically is I connected the iPad to my Mac with a cord (with Web Inspector enabled on both the Mac and iPad), opened Safari > Develop > my iPad, and typed my website URL into the address line. Was that the wrong way to go about it?

And here's code if that helps:

Below is what I did (in brief). What I expected was to have the control not have the "Error" text or the airplay button and for it to have a volume control in addition to the playback speed functionality.

Here's what I *believe* is the relevant html:

```
      <table id="myTable">          
         <th id="thSort" onclick="sortTable(0)">Key</th>
         <th id="thSort" onclick="sortTable(1)">Tune</th>
         <th id="Mp3Heading">Mp3</th>
         <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>Acrobat's New Trick</td>
            <td>
               <audio class="myAudio" controls>
                  <source src="Music/Acrobat's New Trick.mp3">
               </audio>                       
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>Across The Sea</td>
            <td>
               <audio class="myAudio" controls>
                  <source src="Music/Across the Sea.mp3">
               </audio>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>Altamont</td>
            <td>
               <audio class="myAudio" controls>
                  <source src="Music/Altamont.mp3">
               </audio>
         </tr>
```

Here's what I believe is the relevant CSS:

```
    audio {
    width: 300px;
    height: 25px;
    }

    audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    background-color: #e6ebe5;
    color: #e6ebe5;
    }
```

The only script I added for the audio element is this (to set the player back to the beginning once the user hits pause):

```
        <script>
            const myAudio = document.getElementsByClassName ("myAudio");
            for (let i=0; i<myAudio.length; i++)
            myAudio[i].addEventListener("pause", (event) => {
                event.target.currentTime = 0;
            })    
       </script>
```

Comment: Elements will just look different across platforms and browsers, that is fairly normal. Styling is one part, but functionality is also another. If you want something standardised, you will be looking at creating your own interface. With respect to the error, my iPad is not getting the problem you have, but rather the audio elements just keep buffering. I would recommend starting with a single element, loading  close to 170 mp3 files on page load is a _big_ ask for any browser. Some may deal with it, but it does not surprise me that a browser may just give up trying and throw an error

Comment: The type of structure you are making, it would very unusual to write the html by hand. Rather, you probably want to have a server backend generate it for you. Given this is on GitHub pages, you do not have that at your disposal not without fiddling with GitHub actions, which is a bit of a leap from where you are. You could do it in JavaScript, but I really think your first approach should be to simply load **1** file in this table format, then **2**. After that you will want to look pagination and loading dynamically (i.e. only when the users explicitly asks, not on page load).

Comment: With respect to your file paths, be careful of capitalisation. e.g. It isn't `Music/Wild%20Horses%20At%20Stoney%20Point.mp3` but rather `Music/Wild%20Horses%20at%20Stoney%20Point.mp3`. I would suggest dropping the spaces in the file names and transforming it all to lower case (i.e. `music/wild_horses_at_stoney_point.mp3`) to avoid that problem. It is creating a stumbling block that makes it very easy to make a mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much! Tonight I'll try removing rows and adding back in one at a time... ish. :-) I'll also check the names. I'm hoping to eventually use a server/database, but am taking the "Agile" approach while I learn up.